# Problemas para embeber vídeos de Youtube de una emisión de Hangout on Air

Tags: youtube, embebido

En la última semana he tenido un problema, el cual es el siguiente:

Creo un evento en Hangout on air, el cual a su vez crea tres enlaces uno de los cuales en el código de embebido, al insertarlo en un sitio web aparece un error

Revisando la url del vídeo se muestra que la opción de embebido ha sido bloqueada.

Ha varias personas que usan el servicio les ha sucedido la misma situación, en la opción que indica que no se pueden asociar embebidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Ahora para poder embeber un contenido online es necesario asociarlo a una cuenta de Adsense?

No sé si alguno le ha sucedido esta situación, ya plantee mi duda en el foro de ayuda de Youtube, pero al día de hoy no he recibido respuesta.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=first_post_notification_action#!msg/youtube-es/d2rfmuZIwvM/8IxBBgVHCgAJ

Nota:
La cuenta en la que he realizado las pruebas, se encuentra verificada según los pasos indicados por el sitio.

Comment: 1. La solución ya está indicada: "debes tener __vinculada__ una cuenta de YouTube" (ojo que dice __vinculada a YouTube__ y no _verificada_). 2. No parece que esté dentro del alcance del sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, ya realicé los pasos para hacer el proceso, pero aún así el problema persiste, para vincular Adsense a mi cuenta de Youtube (que es lo que entiendo que indica el mensaje) se deben cumplir una serie de requisitos, además de ser pago, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?